# Javascript Lodash - replace object in object

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an object like this:

```
{
    "memory": {
        "memory1":{
            "schedule":"every day",
            "measure": [
                { "date": "date 1", "value": "10" }
            ]
        },
        "memory2": {
            "schedule":"every month",
            "measure": [
                { "date": "date 2", "value": "40" },
                { "date": "date 3", "value": "22" }
            ]
        },
        "memory3": {
            "schedule": "every day",
            "measure": []
        }
    },
    "loads": {
        "load1": {
            "schedule":"every day",
            "measure": [
                { "date": "date 4", "value": "40" }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Given a **name** (that in this object is `memory` and `loads`) and a **type** (that in this object is `memory1`, `memory2`, `memory2` for *memory* and `load1` for *loads*

I need to add another object to **measure** element, searching for his name and type.

For example, given **memory** and **memory2** as variable value and an object `{ "date": "date 1", "value": "10" }`, i will need to concatenate this to measure on the second element (that is memory2) in the first tree that is memory.

I will need too maintain the "measure" array no more than 10 elements (FIFO strategy) but this is another story....

Right now i have created an new object with the new measure, but how to "replace" or "concat" it in the right tree place?

The result should be:

```
{
    "memory": {
        "memory1":{
            "schedule":"every day",
            "measure": [
                { "date": "date 1", "value": "10" }
            ]
        },
        "memory2": {
            "schedule":"every month",
            "measure": [
                { "date": "date 2", "value": "40" },
                { "date": "date 3", "value": "22" },
                { "date": "date 3", "value": "22" }  THIS IS THE ELEMENT TO ADD
            ]
        },
        "memory3": {
            "schedule": "every day",
            "measure": []
        }
    },
    "loads": {
        "load1": {
            "schedule":"every day",
            "measure": [
                { "date": "date 4", "value": "40" }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this about accessing and setting the object property values dynamically..?

Comment: schedule and measure property are "static" all the others property are dynamic. In some tree i can have memory and loads, in other trees i can have doors and desk (the first two name that came to my mind :)). The same for load1, memory1 etc. I need to find this names in the tree and then make the replace. But, i think the only way is to iterate along the tree and chech for `===`

Answer (score 0):

In order to access and modify the nested  object property values dynamically you can utilize an Object method like `Object.prototype.getNestedValue()` It takes a series of strings or integers as arguments (strings for object properties and integers for array indices) in the order of how they are nested. Lets see...

```js
Object.prototype.getNestedValue = function(...a) {
  return a.length > 1 ? (this[a[0]] !== void 0 && this[a[0]].getNestedValue(...a.slice(1))) : this[a[0]];
};

var data = {
    "memory": {
        "memory1":{
            "schedule":"every day",
            "measure": [
                { "date": "date 1", "value": "10" }
            ]
        },
        "memory2": {
            "schedule":"every month",
            "measure": [
                { "date": "date 2", "value": "40" },
                { "date": "date 3", "value": "22" }
            ]
        },
        "memory3": {
            "schedule": "every day",
            "measure": []
        }
    },
    "loads": {
        "load1": {
            "schedule":"every day",
            "measure": [
                { "date": "date 4", "value": "40" }
            ]
        }
    }
},
newMeasureData = { "date": "date 3", "value": "22" };
data.getNestedValue("memory","memory2","measure").push(newMeasureData);
console.log(JSON.stringify(data,null,2));
```